# Understanding the Quotient Space of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ by the Orthogonal Group $O(n)$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, representation-theory, group-actions, matrix-decomposition

I am interested in exploring the structure of the quotient space formed by the action of the orthogonal group $O(n)$ on the space of $n\times m$ real matrices $\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and $m>n$. Specifically, I am considering the action defined by left multiplication:

$$
Q\cdot A = QA, for\ Q\in O(n), A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}.
$$

I would like to understand the geometric and algebraic properties of the quotient space $\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}/O(n)$, where the equivalence classes are formed by the orbits of this action.

**Question**: What is the explicit structure of the quotient space $\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}/O(n)$ or is there any method to obtain it?

**Simple Attempt**: My previous thought is doing by QR decomposition so that quotient space could be described by a set of upper triangular matrices. However, since $m>n$, the decomposition to those upper triangular matrices is not unique.

Any insights, references, or suggestions for further reading would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems like a minimal condition is if two elements are equivalent, their rows have the same span. N9t sure if this is an iff case - if so, the quotient is equal to the set of subspaces of $\mathbb R^m$ of dimension $\leq n.$ There isn't really a good algebra on this space - it can't be made a vector space or a any kind of group.

Comment: Whoops, that would be the result for the quotient with $GL(n),$ not $O(n).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition). Left multiplication by orthogonal matrices lets you arbitrarily shuffle around the left singular vectors but leaves the singular values and the right singular vectors unaffected.

More precisely, the orbit of a matrix $A$ is exactly determined by the decomposition of $\mathbb{R}^m$ into a direct sum of the orthogonal eigenspaces of the symmetric matrix $A^T A$ (these are a completely unique version of the right singular vectors) together with the eigenvalues of $A^T A$ acting on each of these (these are the squares of the singular values).

**Edit:** Ah, there's an easier way to say this: the orbit of $A$ is just determined by $A^T A$, full stop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does it mean that there is no explicit vector space for quotient $\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}/O(n)$ if repeated eigenvalues exist in $A^T A$? In this case, there could be infinite $V$ in svd $A=U\Sigma V^T$ and $\Sigma V^T$ cannot be uniquely determined.

Comment: @Eddie: there's no natural vector space structure on this quotient. As far as I know it's not even homeomorphic to a vector space.

Comment: @Mariano: with the $m > n$ condition in the OP we also need to add the condition that the rank is $\le n$.