# Moduli space for $A\sim B$ if $A(D)=B(D)$ for unit ball $D$ and $A,B:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ linear

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, moduli-space

For two linear maps $A, B:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^n$, define the relation:

$$
A\sim B \qquad \iff \qquad A(D_n) = B(D_n) \tag1
$$
where $D_n$ denotes the $n$-dimensional ball:
$$
D_n=\{x\in\Bbb R^n ~/~ \|x\|_2=1\} \tag2
$$

Obviously, $\sim$ is an equivalence relation, and the question arises what's a moduli space for $M/\!\sim$, $~M=\{\varphi ~/~ \varphi:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n, \varphi\text{ linear} \}$.

Now for any orthogonal $Q\in O(n,\Bbb R)$, the unit ball is invariant under the action of such $Q$, and hence

$$
Q\text{ orthogonal} ~\implies~ A\sim AQ \tag3
$$
and also
$$
Q\text{ orthogonal} ~\implies~ Q\sim \operatorname{Id}_n \tag4
$$
where I think the latter could be an equivalence actually.

For the case of regular $A$, i.e. $A\in\operatorname{GL}(n,\Bbb R)\subset M$, due to $(3)$ we get

$$\begin{align}
\dim(\operatorname{GL}(n,\Bbb R)/\!\sim) 
&= \dim(\operatorname{GL}(n,\Bbb R)) - \dim (O(n,\Bbb R)) \\
&= n^2-1 - n(n-1)/2 \\
&= n(n+1)/2 -1\\ \tag5
\end{align}$$

but for non-regular mappings, there will be lower dimensional "appendages" (borders?).

Comment: You can show that knowing $A(D_n)$ is equivalent to knowing the left singular spaces and the singular values of $A$ so in fact (3) is an iff and the answer is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4756002/understanding-the-quotient-space-of-mathbbrn-times-m-by-the-orthogonal-g/4756028#4756028